# CSS overlay and active buttons

Tags: html, css, button, jquery-mobile

I am building a mobile application with jquery mobile. But I have a problem with my segment control. Like you can see [here](http://formations.emsecure.net/SelligentMobile/index.aspx?ID=jNkkkW%2bwOCbHlvPyJqfW451401ZZZf4LNNzL5H) .

Now what I want to achieve is that when I select a button,the background from this button gets a different background-color.

Here you can find my HTML

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" > 
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-view"  data-icon="segment-titlestyle-segonly"  id="segment1" value="choice1" checked="checked" /> 
                  <label for="segment1"  id="controls"><span class="ui-btn-text-controls">Iedereen</span></label> 
                <input type="radio" name="radio-view" data-icon="segment-titlestyle-segonly" id="segment2" value="choice2" /> 
                    <label for="segment2" id="controls"><span class="ui-btn-text-controls">Team</span></label> 
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-view" data-icon="segment-titlestyle-segonly" id="segment3" value="choice3" /> 
                    <label for="segment3" id="controls"><span class="ui-btn-text-controls">Favorieten</span></label>  
                </fieldset>
```

Like you can see I use for the background the id controls.

```
   #controls{
        background-color: #C0C0C0 !important;
        border-color: black !important;
    }

#controls:overlay{
    background-color: #C0C0C0 !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work. does anybody can help me ?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with pure css. Write like this:-

```
 #controls{
        background-color: #C0C0C0 ;
        border-color: black ;
    }

   #controls:hover{
    background-color: red;
    display:inline-block;    
    }

input[type='radio']:checked + #controls{
    background:red;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Fa3rp/3/

Comment: it' doesnt work with me. But I think it is because I use the jquery mobile framework

Answer (score 0):

Very first thing you **should not assign same ID more than one time** use class instead. Second if you want to change any style on base of selection, you need to create a class and switch through jquery. You an use addClass and removeClass.